# Apache2 Linux GoDaddy

Tags: html, linux

Hi I'm new to website development and I am trying to configure a number of websites from my home based server using Apache2 and Linux Mint.

I have setup three new websites in addition to the 000-default page.I have created the Virtual Host config files in sites-available and have added the sites to Host.conf. Internally(on the server in a browser) they are all working fine - I can access all four sites using localhost or the URLs I've configured them with -tested with and without the www. prefix and all seems fine. The four sites are just basic HTML scripts with different headers and different one line body.

I've added Listen 8090 to Listen 80 on my ports.conf file and have opened port 80 and 8090 on my firewall and have updated Port Forwarding on my router and tested they are open using PortCheckTool. The two ports are open and every other port is locked out so that seems good too.

I've tried to configure a GoDaddy domain name to direct activity to one of these sites. The domain name that works internally (on the server in a browser) is the same as my GoDaddy domain name I've bought. I've been into my GoDaddy account and pointed this domain at my external IP address (tried also adding port to forwarding 8090 as well as leaving port number as default). However when I access this domain from my mobile phone using 3G with WIFI turned off I just get sent to the 000-default homepage.Same using default Port 80 and with Port Forwarding to 8090. I have script for both 80 and 8090 in my site config files in sites-available directory.

So the connection is getting to the server, ports are OK, it's just that apache2 doesn't redirect the GoDaddy traffic but redirects fine locally on the server for the same site!?

Any ideas what I am missing?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)